# Parse the Subject name of a X.509 certificate to a buffer

Tags: c, visual-studio, cryptography, pki, mbedtls

i'm trying to parse the subject name of a X.509 certificate into a buffer , but i'm receiving negative value. What could have been gone wrong?

```
   int32_t ret;
   size_t n = 0;
   uint8_t *p = NULL;
   mbedtls_x509_crt testcert;
   mbedtls_x509_crt_init(&testcert);
   if (ret = mbedtls_x509_crt_parse_file(&testcert, "testcert.pem"))
   {
     printf(" failed\n  !  mbedtls_x509_crt_parse_file returned -0x%04x\n\n", -ret);
     return ret;
   }
   ret = mbedtls_x509_dn_gets(p, n, &testcert.subject);
   if (ret <= 0)
   {
      printf("mbedtls_x509_dn_gets returned %02x", -ret);
      return ret;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake i made in the above code snippet.

1. I was not assigning memory for pointer **p**
2. **"n"** is supposed to be the **Maximum size of buffer**

After correcting these two things i was able to get the CN parsed to a buffer.

Thank you

Comment: p = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
   ret = mbedtls_x509_dn_gets(p, MAX_DATA_SIZE, &clientcert.subject);      MAX_DATA_SIZE = 4096